# Как очистить историю браузера?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой код:

```
<input type="text"><br>
<a href="https://www.google.ru/">google.com</a>
```

если в поле input ввести любой текст, и нажать на ссылку, потом в браузере кликнуть стрелку чтобы вернуться на предыдущую страницу, то в поле input останется введённый текст.
Как этого можно избежать, т.е. чтобы поле очистилось?
как очистить историю браузера в введённый полях, возвращаясь на предыдущую страницу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте HTML-атрибут `autocomplete="off"` для полей

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"><br>
<a href="https://www.google.ru/">google.com</a>
```

Либо как вариант очищать js'ом

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type=\"text\"]").each(function(){
        $(this).val("");
    });
});
```

Comment: кстати возник вопрос, а как очистить `select`, т.е. выбранный `option`? autocomplete="off" не подходит для `select`. сразу не спросил про `select` решил, что решение подойдёт и для `select`

Comment: ну видимо вам поможет js?)

Comment: а если от `select` зависит контент, который грузится с помощью `ajax`? создал тему, можете подсказать?     https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997394/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-select-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e