# При возврате назад в браузере восстановить значения `select` по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Есть класс `Table`  с методами `render` и `get_select`.

```
$table = new Table($workName);
```

метод `$table->render()` возвращает готовый html-код таблицы с ценами, на основе переданного названия таблицы в конструктор `Table`.
т.е. вызов `$table->render()` возвратит таблицу с ценами:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>11$</td><td>12$</td>
    </tr>
...
и т.д.
```

метод `$table->get_select()` возвращает готовый код `select option` со списком работ(таблиц), которые выводятся вышеприведённым методом. 
У каждой работы разные таблицы с ценами, которые формируются динамически в методе `render`.
Страница со списком работ и таблицей формируется вызовом этих двух методов.
Выбирая работу из `select` с помощью `ajax` на странице отображается выбранная таблица с ценами, сформированная методом `$table->render()` и отображается новая таблица без перезагрузки страницы.
есть js-обработчик для `select`

```
change_table_work: function(e){
    var work = this.value;
    ...
    $.ajax(
        succes:function(resp){
            $('.table-wrapper').html(resp.table);
        }
    )
}
```

Вобщем проблема в том, как сделать, чтобы если пользователь выбрал работу с помощью `select`, потом перешёл на какую-то другую страницу, а потом кликнул в браузере стрелку назад чтобы вернуться на предыдущую страницу с работами, как сделать, чтобы была выбрана таблица по умолчанию?
А сейчас при возврате назад на предыдущую страницу, отображается выбранная пользователем страница, а не та, что отображается по умолчанию

Comment: не пробовали вешать событие `window.location.reload(false)` при загрузке страницы `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @radar4ick, а что должно быть? страница из-за вашего кода начинается сама себя перезагружать постоянно без остановки

Comment: хм..может быть если отследить нажатие кнопки "назад" в браузере и перед тем как покинуть событие делать запись в localstorage, и при загрузке прошлой страницы проверять, если значение в localstorage = true, то перезагрузи страницу, чтобы дефолтные значения подгрузились

Comment: @radar4ick, а как можно отследить нажатие кнопки "назад"?

Comment: addEventListener("popstate",function(e){
    console.log("Что-то");
},false);
[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event)

Comment: @radar4ick, вы хоть сами пробовали то что пишете? ничего не работает

Comment: addEventListener("popstate",function(e){alert('test');},false); ничего не выводится при клике назад